# why can't I set some headers on Request object?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, request-headers

I'm trying to request a rest API that needs authentication with a token. When constructing the Request object, some headers disappear.
Why can't I set my Authorization header ?

```
let http_headers = {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        'Authorization': 'Token token='+my_token,
        'Accept': 'Application/json'
    };

let url = this.base_url + '/api/v1/test';
let init =  {
            method: "POST",
            headers: new Headers(http_headers),
            mode: 'no-cors',
            credentials: 'omit' // I try that, but it doesn't seem to have effect
        };
let req = new Request( url, init );
console.log(req.headers.get("Accept")); // Application/json
console.log(req.headers.get("Authorization")); // null, why ?
```

Comment: What is `Request`? Is it [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)? Or maybe [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-request)? Are you using Node.js or a browser? Why is this tagged [tag:fetch-api] when you are using some `Request` object and not `fetch`?

Comment: You said `mode: 'no-cors',` - is this a cross-origin request? Or a same-origin request?

Comment: @Quentin this is the Request from fetch API : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request.
I originally (and aims to) use fetch(url,init).

The url is from another domain.

Comment: Where did you define `my_token`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the documentation for [mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode)

> `no-cors` — **Prevents** the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET or POST, and **the headers from being anything other than simple headers**. If any ServiceWorkers intercept these requests, they may not add or override any headers except for those that are simple headers. In addition, JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting Response. This ensures that ServiceWorkers do not affect the semantics of the Web and prevents security and privacy issues arising from leaking data across domains.

Set the mode to `same-origin` or `cors` to allow credentials to be set.

Comment: Thanks, so I have another pb. I added 'no-cors' previously because I thought it was the pb. I'll check that deeper.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the fetch function and set the headers in the options parameter.

```
fetch(url, { //fetch options
        method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
        cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            // Your headers here
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    })
    .then(); // parse response
```

Borrowed from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

The fetch function returns a Promise that will have the Response object containing data from your api.

Comment: I've used Request because Fetch did not work and I didn't get debug info with it. (and catch error did not work)
As said, I have another pb to investigate. thanks.